# how to add an image as a struct using pixmap in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, pixmap

I created an image in a file:

```
(define zero-zero (add-curve
                   (rectangle 35 60 "solid" "white")
                   0 30 0 0
                   36 30 0 0
                   "black"))
```

I renamed it in a new file as a struct:

```
(define-struct Ficha (nombre valor))
(define 0-0 (make-Ficha "zero-zero" zero-zero))
```

And I created a window to display the image on it using pixmap, the idea was generating this image in the rectangle created on the window: however, it doesn't display it:

```
 (define ventana (open-viewport "ventana" 1200 600))
 ((draw-rectangle ventana) (make-posn 50 50) 1100 300 "black")
(((draw-pixmap (Ficha-valor 0-0) ventana)(make-posn 60 400 ))
```

My question for you guys is how can you add an image using a structure with pixmap or if you can please suggest another function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `draw-pixmap` wants the path to a file it can read, not an image object.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Do you maybe know how to make it works using a structure?